# Measure AWS SES usage per domain / Per client / Sub-account

Tags: amazon-ses

I provide SES Services to many of my clients in different regions of the world. So their apps send out emails through my AWS SES account. It has become a problem to trace out how to measure their usage and stats, IAM wise or some other ways and then be able to bill them for what they have consumed. There must be a way to break stats into some kind of Sub Accounts or something

Can someone help regarding this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for such fine-grained monitoring, according to the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html):

### Feedback notifications

This option allows the most detailed reporting for your billing needs. However, it also requires more work on your part, because you need to build handlers (i.e. lambda functions) which will log sending/bounces/complaints in some persistence (i.e. DynamoDB table). More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-sns.html).

### Event publishing

This option uses CloudWatch for persistence and you have the (probably) familiar CloudWatch UI for reporting. You will have to enforce (*somehow*) your clients to use a AWS specific SMTP header or `SendEmail` / `SendRawEmail` API calls. Less work on your part but you need to find a way to make your clients *help you*. More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html).